# Custom dialog show's no title on Android 7.1.1

Tags: android

I'm creating and showing a custom dialog with the following code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
EvaInputDialog dialog = EvaInputDialog.newInstance(route.getEva());
dialog.show(fm, "evaInputDialog");
```

And in the EvaInputDialog class I set the dialog title like this:

```
public class EvaInputDialog extends DialogFragment {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_eva_input, container, false);

        getDialog().setTitle("EVA AANPASSEN");

        // ...

        return view;
    }

}
```

But the dialog is show without the title.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert);
```

to

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
```

did the trick.